# Django filter on TimeField

Tags: python, django, django-orm

In my model I have a TimeField:

```
time = models.TimeField(db_index=True)
```

Now I have to filter by this value:
for example I need to make something like: `time == "12:30"`

**** EDIT *****

I need also to make something like: time is in a range : `from 12:15 to 12:15`

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(time__contains='16:23')
```

If you use this instead:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(time='16:23')
```

You will never find it since `TimeField` objects are save including milliseconds: `datetime.time(16, 23, 23, 952151)`

**Edit:**

Ok, assuming you have strings you can do something like this:

```
begin = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:14', '%H:%M').time()
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:16', '%H:%M').time()
result = YourModel.objects.filter(time__range=(begin, end))
```

Comment: @Safari is that what you need? It's not tested but I'm pretty sure it could work