# query times within time range with exclusion/specific case

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Assume I have **Item** model which have a start and end timefield.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
```

I need to get all Items which are in a specific range (between some start and end),

BUT,

assume I have two Items in my database:

**Item 1** that start 5pm and end 8pm

and

**Item 2** that start 8pm and end 11pm

I want to query to get all Items that are **between and on (inclusive) 5pm to 8pm**,
so it should **only return the Item 1**, and even though Item 2 starts at 8pm, **I do not want Item 2**, because the end on Item 2 is different than the start of Item 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django filter on TimeField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552558/django-filter-on-timefield)

Comment: nope, not a duplicate.

Comment: please see the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query check explicitly for `gte` and `lte`.

```
qs = Item.objects.filter(start__gte=<given_start>, end__lte=<given_end>)
```

Comment: I have fixed the problem and this isn't necessarily the answer, it's more the fact that I didn't illustrate the problem accurately. thanks for the input.